# The number is added instead of taken away and i dont know why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still messing around In Tkinter but trying to make a balance currently as well as a spent list. This should in theory every time it is triggered decrease the spent value by 10. But it instead increases it by 10

I've already tried moving around where Spent2 is defined but I just get a not defined error. I think it might be because of the fact that it becomes a negative number? So when I take the spent2 value from the Balance value it adds it instead. If so how would I get round the problem

Member class

```
class Member:
    year = 0
    spent2 = 0
    def __init__(self, name, rank, spent):
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.spent = spent

    def sal(self):
        rank10 = str(int(self.rank) * 100)
        print(self.name +" is earning "+ rank10)

    def bal_year(self):
        bal10 = str(int(self.rank) * 100 * int(self.year) - int(self.spent))
        print(self.name +" has £"+ bal10)
```

Sp10 Called

```
def bread():
    br=Tk()

    def sp(old:Tk):
        old.destroy()
        Tiger()
        sp10()




    br.title('Bread')
    l4 = Label(br, text="What would you like to buy Tiger bread, a Bageutte or a Loaf Bread?").pack()
    br1 = Button(br, text = "Buy Tiger Bread", command = lambda: sp(br))
    br1.pack()
```

Changing Spent value

```
def sp10():
    Member.spent2 = (Member.spent2 - int(10))
```

A test of my Class Member

```
def balance():
    doppy = Member("DoppyRex", "6", Member.spent2)
    doppy.bal_year()
```

I expect it to decrease the overall balance by 10 but it increases it by 10 instead.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include your actual and desired output?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Is `spent2` an attriubte of `Member` class?

Comment: Also I think I would have to add most of the code from my thing into that?

Comment: Yes Ill add the member class

Comment: What do you want reduced? what is `Spent2` where are you calling sp10?

Comment: @Doppy just add the `Member` class. You can spare the `tkinter` part

Comment: Ill add where I call sp10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are lowering the amount spent:

```
def sp10():
    Member.spent2 = (Member.spent2 - int(10))
```

by 10, which means the balance at

```
bal10 = str(int(self.rank) * 100 * int(self.year) - int(self.spent))
```

is increased by 10, because you subtract self.spent.

Comment: Thanks so just change the - to a plus?

Comment: Yes, you probably want to be increasing the spent value by 10.

Comment: These things are always harder to spot than you'd think. Glad I could help.